# quiver plot in Python using 2D arrays

Tags: python, matplotlib

Hi I am trying to use the quiver plot to create a vector field plot.  Here is my logic and approach, I first create the x,y coordinates for position by np.arange and use a step size of 0.1.  Then I mesh the grid for x,y.  Then I import the x component of the function Fx, and the y component Fy into python as .dat files.  The .dat files are each 2D arrays (just a square matrix).  I then use the quiver command for the meshed x,y coordinates and the Fx,Fy 2d arrays.  However the quiver plot output does not make much sense at all in terms of what I was expecting.

Is there a problem with my code that I am overlooking?  Does np.arange work if the step size is not an integer amount? I printed out all the arrays to manually check the data and everything seems fine.

Could it be that my four 2D arrays do not all have the same shape?  The two .dat files I import are each 40x40 square matrices.   Not sure if this is matching up well with the grid I meshed.

Other than that, I am unsure as to what the issue is.  Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  I can add the data in my .dat file if that will help.  Thanks! ( I have checked all other examples on stack overflow for this problem and it seems my code is logically correct so I am very stuck)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.genfromtxt('file1.dat')
data2 = np.genfromtxt('file2.dat')

nx = 2
ny = 2
x=np.arange(-nx,nx,0.1)
y=np.arange(-ny,ny,0.1)
xi,yi=np.meshgrid(x,y)
Fx = data[::5] #picks out every 5 rows in the matrix
Fy = data2[::5] 
#print(Fx)
#print(Fy)
#print(xi)
#print(yi)

plt.axes([0.065, 0.065, 0.9, 0.9])
plt.quiver(xi,yi,Fx,Fy, alpha=.5)
plt.quiver(xi,yi,Fx,Fy, edgecolor='k',facecolor='none', linewidth=.5)

plt.show()
```

EDIT: .dat files below as asked.  If there is a way to import the .dat file let me know, I realize this is a lot of numbers and formatted horribly.  Fx is listed first, then the Fy array.  I am expecting a very nice quiver plot in which I have some kind of circular pattern/ circular flow. The arrows should all form a clockwise and or counter clockwise flow.

```
  -30.9032192      0.512708426      0.511251688      0.508112907      0.503038108      0.495766401      0.486015081      0.473499298      0.457935333      0.439051390      0.416606665      0.390406251      0.360321403      0.326310992      0.288441181      0.246901810      0.202013552      0.154238343      0.104165822       5.24933599E-02   0.00000000      -5.24933599E-02 -0.104165822     -0.154238343     -0.202013552     -0.246901810     -0.288441181     -0.326310992     -0.360321403     -0.390406251     -0.416606665     -0.439051390     -0.457935333     -0.473499298     -0.486015081     -0.495766401     -0.503038108     -0.508112907     -0.511251688     -0.512708426       30.9032192    

  0.640149713      0.648661256      0.646115780      0.638335168      -13.4731970      -13.0613079      0.587181866      0.561966598      0.533295572      0.501472771      0.466741979      0.429292738      0.389282435      0.346857786      0.302170664      0.255400449      0.206771404      0.156560570      0.105099753       5.27719632E-02   2.10129052E-08  -5.27718328E-02 -0.105099864     -0.156560570     -0.206771582     -0.255400449     -0.302170008     -0.346857607     -0.389282405     -0.429292321     -0.466741502     -0.501472294     -0.533295095     -0.561966538     -0.587181747       13.0613060       13.4731960     -0.638335109     -0.646115661     -0.648661256     -0.640149713    

  0.799892545      0.824215114      0.801061392      0.776797950      0.753669202      0.730814993      0.707295001      0.682291210      0.655105412      -8.68122292      -8.12608242      0.554765701      0.513439834      0.467435867      0.416336209      0.359773695      0.297508597      0.229575798      0.156477526       7.93530941E-02   6.53175791E-10  -7.93530941E-02 -0.156477645     -0.229576021     -0.297508597     -0.359773695     -0.416336179     -0.467435598     -0.513440192     -0.554765582       8.12608242       8.68122387     -0.655105233     -0.682291508     -0.707294881     -0.730815291     -0.753669143     -0.776797950     -0.801061392     -0.824215114     -0.799892545    

  0.940612555      0.983826339      0.933131218      0.884394646      0.842061043      0.804476202      0.769944012      0.737089813      0.704840183      0.672395170      0.639202237      0.604933023      0.569452882      0.532750905      0.494812310      -2.68859553      -2.16188312      0.365726620      0.304749787      0.205249593       6.78142031E-09 -0.205249622     -0.304749817     -0.365726680       2.16188359       2.68859553     -0.494812399     -0.532750905     -0.569453001     -0.604932964     -0.639202118     -0.672395170     -0.704840362     -0.737089515     -0.769943893     -0.804476202     -0.842061162     -0.884394407     -0.933131695     -0.983826339     -0.940612555    

  0.999167860       1.05166125      0.986028075      0.923735499      0.870001256      0.822448075      0.778727889      0.736939847      0.695574820      0.653458953      0.609715879      0.563743949      0.515199065      0.463976830      0.410177410      0.354019582      0.295616359      0.234412342      0.167968050       9.07804966E-02  -8.54922577E-10  -9.07804891E-02 -0.167968005     -0.234412268     -0.295616418     -0.354019672     -0.410177410     -0.463976830     -0.515199006     -0.563743949     -0.609715819     -0.653458893     -0.695574880     -0.736939907     -0.778727889     -0.822448075     -0.870001316     -0.923735559     -0.986028075      -1.05166125     -0.999167860    


  0.940612555      0.983826339      0.932870448      0.884094179      0.841758013      0.804004610      0.768958390      0.735091329      0.701199591      0.666386902      0.630052805      0.591893077      0.551910400      0.510422051      0.468044579      0.425626040      0.384017974      0.343483299      0.302600116     -0.377980769       8.43500270E-10  0.377980769     -0.302600116     -0.343483359     -0.384017944     -0.425625950     -0.468044549     -0.510422230     -0.551910520     -0.591892898     -0.630052805     -0.666386902     -0.701199770     -0.735090971     -0.768958986     -0.804005086     -0.841758251     -0.884094059     -0.932870448     -0.983826339     -0.940612555    


 0.799892545      0.824215114      0.807587028      0.790868759      0.775763810      0.761242151      0.746228993      0.729784787      0.711097538      0.689466000      0.664264023      -6.33222771      -5.70436525      0.561126649      0.514991641      0.460934460      0.396892428      0.320130050      0.227872163      0.119494393      -1.02303694E-08 -0.119494416     -0.227872089     -0.320129842     -0.396892160     -0.460934043     -0.514991641     -0.561126769       5.70436525       6.33222771     -0.664264023     -0.689466000     -0.711097836     -0.729784369     -0.746228993     -0.761242330     -0.775764227     -0.790868759     -0.807587445     -0.824215114     -0.799892545 

  0.640149713      0.648661256      0.658376634      0.663496077      0.663335323      -12.7135134      -12.2490902      0.630356669      0.608760655      0.581994295      0.550120413      0.513214111      0.471384048      0.424800932      0.373717010      0.318486720      0.259573966      0.197552294      0.133099481       6.69753179E-02  -1.07370708E-08  -6.69753179E-02 -0.133099481     -0.197552368     -0.259573698     -0.318486512     -0.373717397     -0.424800485     -0.471384078     -0.513214111     -0.550120771     -0.581994355     -0.608760655     -0.630356669       12.2490902       12.7135134     -0.663335383     -0.663496077     -0.658376753     -0.648661256     -0.640149713    

 -30.9032192      0.512708426      0.511251688      0.508112907      0.503038108      0.495766401      0.486015081      0.473499298      0.457935333      0.439051390      0.416606665      0.390406251      0.360321403      0.326310992      0.288441181      0.246901810      0.202013552      0.154238343      0.104165822       5.24933599E-02   0.00000000      -5.24933599E-02 -0.104165822     -0.154238343     -0.202013552     -0.246901810     -0.288441181     -0.326310992     -0.360321403     -0.390406251     -0.416606665     -0.439051390     -0.457935333     -0.473499298     -0.486015081     -0.495766401     -0.503038108     -0.508112907     -0.511251688     -0.512708426       30.9032192
```

Now Fy array:

```
 -0.205083355     -0.525830388     -0.552687049     -0.580741763     -0.609929502     -0.640149713     -0.671258569     -0.703064799     -0.735320449     -0.767719150     -0.799892545     -0.831412077     -0.861791074     -0.890495777     -0.916961849     -0.940612555     -0.960886896     -0.977269113     -0.989315629     -0.996686459     -0.999167860     -0.996686459     -0.989315629     -0.977269113     -0.960886896     -0.940612555     -0.916961849     -0.890495777     -0.861791074     -0.831412077     -0.799892545     -0.767719150     -0.735320449     -0.703064799     -0.671258569     -0.640149713     -0.609929502     -0.580741763     -0.552687049     -0.525830388     -0.205083355    
 -0.495766401     -0.496165156     -0.509083092     -0.549605310       13.5129404       13.0519953     -0.646288395     -0.672055602     -0.695797563     -0.717920899     -0.738660455     -0.758110344     -0.776252687     -0.792979062     -0.808119476     -0.821464479     -0.832787395     -0.841867268     -0.848508835     -0.852558434     -0.853919387     -0.852558374     -0.848508716     -0.841867328     -0.832787514     -0.821464896     -0.808119833     -0.792978704     -0.776252151     -0.758110642     -0.738660395     -0.717920780     -0.695797503     -0.672055602     -0.646288335       13.0519953       13.5129395     -0.549605191     -0.509083092     -0.496165156     -0.495766401    

 -0.416606665     -0.387658477     -0.370003909     -0.412325561     -0.451486528     -0.484789789     -0.512974977     -0.536900580     -0.557342112       8.73137856       8.12754345     -0.604040861     -0.616312325     -0.627466083     -0.637651145     -0.646887839     -0.655064702     -0.661947429     -0.667217672     -0.670547307     -0.671688557     -0.670547426     -0.667217493     -0.661947429     -0.655064702     -0.646887779     -0.637651086     -0.627466381     -0.616312623     -0.604041040       8.12754345       8.73137951     -0.557341993     -0.536900103     -0.512975276     -0.484789670     -0.451485991     -0.412325561     -0.370003909     -0.387658477     -0.416606665   

 -0.246901810     -0.228335708     -0.217398927     -0.246074528     -0.271431714     -0.291785061     -0.307664692     -0.319617361     -0.328106791     -0.333535194     -0.336277753     -0.336733580     -0.335400879     -0.333002120     -0.330682963       2.81363893       2.24033999     -0.348281264     -0.372185618     -0.395866930     -0.403591305     -0.395866960     -0.372185677     -0.348281264       2.24033999       2.81363893     -0.330682874     -0.333002120     -0.335400909     -0.336733490     -0.336277664     -0.333535045     -0.328106642     -0.319617361     -0.307664692     -0.291785270     -0.271431714     -0.246074289     -0.217398927     -0.228335708     -0.246901810    
   0.00000000      -3.97699699E-02  -8.22334886E-02  -9.01840925E-02  -9.43243951E-02  -9.68469381E-02  -9.79287177E-02  -9.75681171E-02  -9.57226083E-02  -9.23085213E-02  -8.71856511E-02  -8.01347122E-02  -7.08276853E-02  -5.87978214E-02  -4.34263758E-02  -2.40071025E-02  -4.12676527E-05   2.79203784E-02   5.66387177E-02   7.90976062E-02   8.76100808E-02   7.90975988E-02   5.66387326E-02   2.79204026E-02  -4.12871887E-05  -2.40071043E-02  -4.34263758E-02  -5.87978400E-02  -7.08276406E-02  -8.01346377E-02  -8.71856511E-02  -9.23085883E-02  -9.57226381E-02  -9.75680798E-02  -9.79286432E-02  -9.68469679E-02  -9.43244398E-02  -9.01841149E-02  -8.22335258E-02  -3.97699960E-02   0.00000000    

 0.246901810      0.149554759       5.41899577E-02   6.69130459E-02   8.30149651E-02   9.62892994E-02  0.106718197      0.114569001      0.119987577      0.122970015      0.123354375      0.120809816      0.114815064      0.104622498       8.91864598E-02   6.69886991E-02   3.55363674E-02  -1.02187870E-02  -8.21609423E-02 -0.177876130     -0.191068053     -0.177876085      -8.21608678E-02  -1.02187609E-02   3.55363339E-02   6.69886544E-02   8.91865119E-02  0.104622573      0.114814982      0.120810024      0.123354279      0.122969493      0.119987287      0.114568666      0.106718197       9.62890834E-02   8.30147490E-02   6.69130459E-02   5.41902333E-02  0.149555355      0.246901810    

 0.416606665      0.324635506      0.239433557      0.271107137      0.304715306      0.333829224      0.358776420      0.380251735      0.398895025      0.415270001      0.429880798      -6.52393579      -5.84947205      0.467720896      0.479777455      0.492111117      0.504699171      0.516976655      0.527697802      0.535157621      0.537844956      0.535157681      0.527697802      0.516976714      0.504699290      0.492111027      0.479777277      0.467720628      -5.84947205      -6.52393579      0.429880500      0.415270001      0.398895413      0.380252063      0.358776003      0.333829224      0.304715246      0.271106362      0.239433587      0.324635804      0.416606665    

 0.495766401      0.468931794      0.452914894      0.491556555      0.528390408      -12.8101072      -12.3052654      0.617275119      0.641844690      0.664552093      0.685565233      0.704941750      0.722658634      0.738638997      0.752775729      0.764953554      0.775063336      0.783014059      0.788738489      0.792190075      0.793342948      0.792190075      0.788738668      0.783013999      0.775063157      0.764953852      0.752775729      0.738638759      0.722658694      0.704941571      0.685565174      0.664552152      0.641844690      0.617275119      -12.3052645      -12.8101072      0.528390408      0.491556555      0.452914953      0.468931794      0.495766401  

0.512708426      0.525830388      0.552687049      0.580741763      0.609929502      0.640149713      0.671258569      0.703064799      0.735320449      0.767719150      0.799892545      0.831412077      0.861791074      0.890495777      0.916961849      0.940612555      0.960886896      0.977269113      0.989315629      0.996686459      0.999167860      0.996686459      0.989315629      0.977269113      0.960886896      0.940612555      0.916961849      0.890495777      0.861791074      0.831412077      0.799892545      0.767719150      0.735320449      0.703064799      0.671258569      0.640149713      0.609929502      0.580741763      0.552687049      0.525830388      0.512708426
```

Comment: Can you post `Fx`, `Fy` and a description of the expected result and/or why the result you are getting is not what you expect?

Comment: Are you sure you are using the same data? From the data you provide the first element is -30 which is not shown in your plot above. Additionally, how are you plotting `Fy(x,0)` in 2D? How do you determine the values of `x`.

Comment: @hashmuke Thanks again for the communication and help.  So, this data is a plot of Fy(x,0), the first element is -.20.  However I actually plotted it for x going from -15 to 15 for the 2D plot above opposed to -2 to 2 as done below in the quiver plot.  I used x from -2 to 2 in the quiver plot just so I can import a .dat file with less points here.  My x,y actually run from -15 to 15 though.

Comment: @hashmuke I determine the values of x in the 1D plot in my fortran code.  I import a .dat file with 2 colums into python, one column x axis, the other column is Fy(x,0).  The x value is just -15 to 15 with a step size of 0.1.  Do you want me to make the 2D plot with x axis from -2 to 2 as in the quiver below? and upload that plot?  If you want in a private chat or via elsewhere, I can just show you the whole dat files with no splicing of data, and x,y running from -15 to 15.  So the Fx,Fy 2D arrays are actually 300 x 300 matrices since my step size is 0.1.

Comment: Can you share the full data using tools like http://www.filedropper.com/ ? The one you pasted above is not bounded between -1 and 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There appear to be unusually large values (perhaps indication of an asymptotic singularity?) along the lines `y=x` and `y=-x`.

You can see this in [the data](http://www.filedropper.com/fxdata) you posted. Consider for example, the first line:

```
  -31.3490391       6.68895245E-02   6.68859407E-02   ... -6.68895245E-02   31.3490391
```

The first value is large and negative, followed by numbers which are  small and positive. Near the end of the line the numbers are small and negative, while the last value is large and positive. Clearly, as it stands, this data is not going to produce a smoothly varying quiver plot.

If we remove these unusually large values:

```
data[np.abs(data) > 1] = np.nan
data2[np.abs(data2) > 1] = np.nan
```

then

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.genfromtxt('file1.dat')
data2 = np.genfromtxt('file2.dat')

data[np.abs(data) > 1] = np.nan
data2[np.abs(data2) > 1] = np.nan

N = 10
Fx = data[::N, ::N]
Fy = data2[::N, ::N]

nrows, ncols = Fx.shape
nx = 2
ny = 2
x = np.linspace(-nx, nx, ncols)
y = np.linspace(-ny, ny, nrows)
xi, yi = np.meshgrid(x, y, indexing='ij')

plt.axes([0.065, 0.065, 0.9, 0.9])
plt.quiver(xi, yi, Fx, Fy, alpha=.5)
plt.quiver(xi, yi, Fx, Fy, edgecolor='k', facecolor='none', linewidth=.5)

plt.show()
```

yields

[image]

---

`data` is a 2D array of shape (301, 301):

```
In [109]: data.shape
Out[109]: (301, 301)
```

If we slice `data` using `data[::10]` then the result has shape

```
In [113]: data[::10].shape
Out[113]: (31, 301)
```

Notice that only the first axis gets sliced. To slice both the first and second axes, use `data[::10, ::10]`:

```
In [114]: data[::10, ::10].shape
Out[114]: (31, 31)
```

See [the docs](http://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/Indexing.html#multidimensional-slices) for more on multidimensional slicing.
Always pay attention to the shape of NumPy arrays. It is often the key to understanding NumPy operations.

---

Although `plt.quiver` can sometimes accept arrays of different shape, 
it is easiest to use `plt.quiver` by passing four arrays the the same shape.
To ensure that `xi, yi, Fx, Fy` all have the same shape, slice `data` and `data2` to form `Fx` and `Fy` *first*, and then build `xi` and `yi` to conform to the (common) shape of `Fx` of `Fy`:

```
nrows, ncols = Fx.shape
x = np.linspace(-nx, nx, ncols)
y = np.linspace(-ny, ny, nrows)
```

The third argument to [`np.linspace`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) indicates the number of elements in the
returned array.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense.  I did notice the unusually large values but was not sure at all how to handle them, now I see how.  I have one question about your code.  Why did you use Fx = data[::N,::N] and not just Fx=data[::N]?  What is the difference exactly?  I know what [::N] does, just not what [::N,::N] does.  This is looking way better than anything I had, thanks a lot.  I think the problem may now be in how I actually generate the data for the Fx.dat, Fy.dat in fortran, as the quiver plot is still not what I expected it to look like, but I know your code is right.  Thanks so much!

Comment: I've added an explanation above.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am very new to python and am learning a lot from what you have showed. I just have to think about all of this now, if I have any more questions I will let you know.

Comment: Hi, just one question for you.  I switched Fx,Fy in the plt.quiver commands and it produced the correct plot.  Do you have any idea how this could be?  Thanks a lot!

Comment: When dealing with `(x,y)` coordinates, the first coordinate refers to the horizontal axis, the the second refers to the vertical axis. But when dealing with 2D NumPy arrays with `(i,j)` coordinates, the first coordinate refers to the (vertical) row and the second coordinate refers to the (horizontal) column. This [fundamental inconsistency](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2014/meshgrids-and-disambiguating-rows-and-columns-from-cartesian-coordinates/) often rears its ugly head when plotting arrays. Instead of swapping `Fx` and `Fy`, you could use: `xi, yi = np.meshgrid(x, y, indexing='ij')`.

Comment: Hi, I have another quiver plot problem. Would you be able to possibly provide any assistance?  You helped me a lot here so I'm now trying to pay attention to the shape of the numpy arrays, and I realize they're not the same, but I can't fix it...  Thank you very much.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68276852/reproducing-matplotlib-gallery-3d-plot-but-arrays-have-different-shape?noredirect=1#comment120674415_68276852

Answer (score 1):

First make sure the dimension for `Fx` and `Fy` is the same to avoid any confusion. Then generate the grid space dimension based on the data dimension. You can use `np.linspace` instead of `np.arange` as:

```
x = np.linspace(-nx, nx, Fx.shape[1])
y = np.linspace(-ny, ny, Fx.shape[0])
```

**Update**:
The complete code looks like:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Fxdata.dat contain Fx data while Fydata.dat is Fy downloaded from the provided link
Fx = np.genfromtxt('Fxdata.dat')
Fy = np.genfromtxt('Fydata.dat')

# input data dimensions 
num_Fx = Fx.shape[0]    # number of lines for the data in file1.dat
length_Fx = Fx.shape[1]  # length of each row for file1.dat 

nx = 15
ny = 15

# you can generate the grid points based on the dimensions of the input data
x = np.linspace(-nx, nx, length_Fx)
y = np.linspace(-ny, ny, num_Fx)

# grid points 
xi,yi=np.meshgrid(x,y)

#
plt.axes([0.065, 0.065, 0.9, 0.9])
plt.quiver(xi,yi,Fx,Fy, alpha=.5)
#plt.quiver(xi,yi,Fx,Fy, edgecolor='k',facecolor='none', linewidth=.5)

plt.show()
```

Not sure if it make sense now but the resulting plot looks like:

[image: Picture using the full data]

Comment: Did you also change `Fx = data[::5]` to `Fx = data` and likewise for `Fy`?

Comment: I used  `Fx` and `Fy` that you provided and their dimension is 9X41.

Comment: Did you use `Fx = np.genfromtxt('file1.dat')`? (Just trying to help the OP reproduce your result.)

Comment: Sorry @ubutbu, I though you asked the question, now I know. Yes, that is right. I saved the data into two files and loaded them using `np.genfromtxt` directly to `Fx` and `Fy`.

Comment: @hashmuke Thanks a lot, can you upload the rest of the code you used?  I am not entirely sure how you imported the data and all.  I have a few questions, what does Fx.shape[1], Fy.shape[0] refer to?  What is the [1] and [0] for?    Thanks again!  Also, why are some arrows huge relative to the others, is that just because of the data set?

Comment: @unutbu I appreciate your help in this problem as well.  I am just not entirely sure how to reproduce the result above, as you pointed out.  Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks for the update.  Can you please explain exactly what you are doing when you used num_Fx and length_Fx?  I  still do not get what that [0] , [1] are referring to.  Are they just arbitrary?  I am working on implementing the code now and understanding it, then I will gladly accept this as the answer.  Thanks.  The plot does not make sense still, but clearly that must be a problem on my end as I assume your code is perfect/fine.  Thanks  again!

Comment: Also, how come you never used Fy until the quiver command line.  You seem to be only using shape for the length of Fx and such.  Is that because they're the same dimension or?

Comment: You are dealing with a 2D array when you use Fx.shape it will return a tuple whose first element is the dimension of the columns while the second element is that of the rows. That is why I used 0 and 1. 
I have already compared the `Fx.shape` and `Fy.shape` they are both (9, 41), so you can use any of the two. 

Can I ask what `Fx`, and `Fy` are in your data? Are they gradient at specific position? Can you also try o use the full data without slicing it as in data[::5].

Comment: @hashmuke Okay let me think about this some more, thanks a lot for the help.  Yes Fx, Fy are exactly that, they have to do with gradients at specific positions.  Fx is a first derivative with respect to x, Fy is a first derivative wrt y.  I can try using the full data however then my plot looks cluttered and its hard to resolve anything at all since there is way too many points/arrows I assume

Comment: I can plot Fx or Fy against x or y just using a 2D plot and the result is correct.  So I am unsure as to why my quiver plot does not look like it's supposed to.  The data I use for the 2D plot is the same data I use for the quiver plot.  So I know the problem must be in python opposed to the data being generated which is done in fortran.

Comment: Can you add to the question the plot that you are getting? You can also plot `Fx` and `Fy` using `plt.imshow(Fx)` & `plt.imshow(Fy)` then add the plot to see if the result is from the data.

Comment: @hashmuke I can plot Fx or Fy against x or y just using a 2D plot and the result is correct.  So I am unsure as to why my quiver plot does not look like it's supposed to.  The data I use for the 2D plot is the same data I use for the quiver plot.  So I know the problem must be in python opposed to the data being generated which is done in fortran.  The reason I spliced  using [::5] is because I figured my data set had too many points so this would make the arrows actually visible.

Comment: @hashmuke I added the 2d plot above to my post.  It is a plot of Fy(x,0) versus x.  Note, in this plot I use the full data set and not the spliced data set since the 2D plot can handle all the points and still look readable.

Comment: Thank you very much for the updated plot using the files I provided.